# Pragma error in Vivado HLS while synthesis

Tags: vivado-hls

Simulation process done without 0 error, but showing error during synthesis. I am unable to find the error.

I am getting an error like this in HLS tool during synthesis:

> "In File included from E:/thaus/fact_L/facoriall/solution1/.autopilot/db/fact.pragma.1.cpp:1"

Header file

```
include "factorial.h"

include "ap_int.h"

typedef ap_int<128> in1_t;

typedef ap_int<1024> out_t;

int factorial(in1_t N);

endif
```

Source File

```
include "factorial.h"

int factorial(in1_t N)

{

pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=N bundle=a

pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=return bundle=a

int i;

out_t fact;

fact=1;

for (i=1; i<=N; i++)

{

fact=fact*i;

}

return fact;

}
```

Test Bench

```
include <stdio.h>

include <stdlib.h>

include "ap_int.h"

include "factorial.h"

int main()

{

in1_t N=50;

out_t  fact=1;

int i;

fact=1;

factorial(N);

for (i=1; i<=N; i++)

{


fact=fact*i;

}

cout << "cout of fact: " << fact;

}
```

Simulation Result

```
make: `csim.exe' is up to date.
cout of fact: 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
@I [SIM-1] CSim done with 0 errors.
```

Comment: What is the next line? (After "in file included...")

Comment: Also, the code doesn't look right in the question. Try editing it and marking it as code.

Comment: This is my error code "In File included from E:/thaus/fact_L/facoriall/solution1/.autopilot/db/fact.pragma.1.cpp:1"  in HLS tool while synthesis.